# Apex 5.1.4 Convert Number to Decimal

Tags: oracle-apex

When a decimal number is entered in apex, it is displayed as `2.3`, is there any simple code to convert it to 3 decimal places such as `2.300`?

Comment: You need it on a client-side or on a server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query use

```
to_char(3.1,'9.900')
```

Or modify the format mask on the column, use the LOV for help

```
999G999G999G999G990D00
```